# Get radius of a circle given segment area and chord length.

Tags: trigonometry

From a circle with radius of $2$ cm and chord length of $1$ cm, I have calculated that the segment area is about $0.042475$ cm$^2$.

If I have the chord length of $1$ cm and the segment area of $0.042475$ cm$^2$, how would I calculate from that the radius in cm?

Comment: If the diameter is $1$ and the chord is $1$, the chord is the diameter and the segment is a semicircle. You mean the radius is $1$, don't you?

Comment: @DavidK: in a circle of radius of $1$, a sector with a chord length of $1$ does have an area of $0.090586$.

Comment: @DavidK, yes it is indeed a semicircle, which is the max chord length you can have, however the question is still the same, from a segment area and a chord length I'd like to know what the diameter (or radius) of the circle is.

Comment: Have you tried writing out the length of the chord and the area of the segment in terms of the radius $r$ and the angle $\theta$ that the chord subtends at the center of the circle?

Comment: @robjohn Working out the $0.090586$ is why I guessed the calculation had been done with radius $1$ rather than diameter $1.$ But it is also true that the question is still meaningful despite this minor point of confusion.

Comment: @DavidK: indeed it is. I have written out an answer, but I am waiting to see if the OP will improve the question before posting it.

Comment: Why was the question edited to make the segment area a whopping $40.042475\ cm^2$? Was that just a typo?

Comment: @fleablood: It looks like a typo, so I fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first para in question is incorrect ( Area should be 0.362344 as chord makes $30^{\circ} $ to x-axis).
Anyway it is not relevant to the question that follows. So ignored.

For question in the second para let the circle equation *in polar coordinates* be

$$r= 2 R \sin t =1 \tag 1$$

Area of segment A
$$= \int \frac12 r^2 dt= \int \frac12 4R^2 \sin^2 t dt= R^2( t- \sin t \cos t )\tag 2 $$

since Boundary Condition :$( t=0, A=0)$ integration constant vanishes.

$$A =R^2( t- \sin t \cos t) \tag 3 $$

Solving 1), 3) together simultaneously for $(R,t)$ by numerical iteration ( because analytical solution not possible, the equation to be solved is transcendental ):

$$ \text{for } r= BC=1,~ t\approx 14.52^{\circ}, ~R=2; $$

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, I now know why I couldn't figure it out myself!